# Do trait default function implementations cause code bloat the same way generics do?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, code-size

I stumbled on [this interesting code example](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-this-a-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/31004/6):

```
trait Bar {
    fn foo(&mut self);
    fn call_foo_twice(&mut self) {
        self.foo(); // <-- this is statically dispatched
        self.foo();
    }
}
```

In C++, if this were a base class instead of a trait, `call_foo_twice` would only be compiled once, but it would dynamically dispatch the calls to `foo`, which itself would be declared virtual.

If those `foo` calls are statically dispatched in Rust, that suggests `call_foo_twice` is going to be recompiled for every single type that implements `Bar` because each type will have its own unique definition of `foo`. Is this correct? For instances where I prefer reducing compile time over increasing performance is there an idiom I should use instead?

Comment: The question title and body appear to be asking for different things. In fact, there are at least 3 distinct questions asked, and it's not entirely clear, what problem you need help with.

Comment: @IInspectable on rereading it still seems clear to me. If I use Bar with 10 different types does the generated code contain one copy of call_foo_twice or ten? If ten, is there a way to make it only 1?

Comment: That question potentially has a different answer than the question: *"How do I reduce compile times?"*. With devirtualization and identical code folding you have 2 powerful optimizations that can effectively fight [code duplication](https://godbolt.org/z/3hTs1T). That can be an answer to the question you asked in the previous comment, but goes against the question asked above with respect to compile times.

Comment: @IInspectable AFAICT neither of those optimizations help prevent the duplicate generation from happening in the first place, which is what bloats the compile time. Also the code won't be identical and so it won't be folded -- if calls are statically dispatched then the code is actually different for different types.